# How to get custom attribute from data given below?

Tags: jquery

I have a div

```
<div class="re-compare-wrap re-compare-wrap-2467" style="display: block;">
    <div class="re-compare-item compare-item-2458" data-compareid="2458" style="display: block;">
        <i class="fa fa-times-circle re-compare-new-close"></i>
        <div class="re-compare-img">
            <a href="">
                <img src="" alt="Xbox One S Minecraft Console Bundle 500GB"></a>
            </div><div class="re-compare-title">
            <a href="">Xbox One S Minecraft Console Bundle 500GB</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="re-compare-item compare-item-2439" data-compareid="2439" style="display: block;">
        <i class="fa fa-times-circle re-compare-new-close"></i>
        <div class="re-compare-img">
            <a href=""><a href="">Sony PlayStation Move Motion Controller – Twin...</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to get `data-compareid` of both the div's here 
I'm using jquery

```
trm = '.re-compare-tab-' + response.pageid +' div';
    var dtmln = '';
    alert('trm ' + trm);
    $(trm).each(function(i, obj){
        dtmln = $(this).data("compareid") + ',';
        alert('dsds '+ dtmln );
    });
```

response.pageid has 2467 number but I'm getting  `dsds` empty.

Comment: `$(this).data("data-compareid")`

Comment: There is no class shown that has `re-compare-tab-` in it. Assuming it is parent of what is shown you are looping every nested `<div>` some of which have no data attribute. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: @ANS used that also but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looping through all divs inside .re-compare-wrap-2467.. try looping only through re-compare-item

```
trm = '.re-compare-wrap-' + response.pageid +' div.re-compare-item';
    var dtmln = '';
    //console.log('trm ' + trm);
    $(trm).each(function(i, obj){

        dtmln = $(this).data("compareid") + ',';
        console.log('dsds '+ dtmln );
    });
```

working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/jinspeter/c7xodh0z/

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Filtering just the divs that have data-comparid:

```
$('div').filter(function (index) {
    return ($(this).attr('data-compareid'));
}).each(function(i,obj){
    alert($(this).prop('class') + ' ' + $(this).attr('data-compareid'));  
    });
```

---

There is no re-compare-tab-2467 div in the code you posted so I guess that there is a parent DIV you didn't posted but that is ok, I just changed the code slightly to use an existant DIV and show you how to read the data-compareid property:

```js
//trm = '.re-compare-wrap-2467 div';
//    var dtmln = '';
//    alert('trm ' + trm);
//    $(trm).each(function(i, obj){
//        dtmln = $(this).attr("data-compareid") + ',';
//        alert('dsds '+ dtmln );
//    });


    
    $('div').filter(function (index) {
        return ($(this).attr('data-compareid'));
    }).each(function(i,obj){
    alert($(this).prop('class') + ' ' + $(this).attr('data-compareid'));  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="re-compare-wrap re-compare-wrap-2467" style="display: block;">
    <div class="re-compare-item compare-item-2458" data-compareid="2458" style="display: block;">
        <i class="fa fa-times-circle re-compare-new-close"></i>
        <div class="re-compare-img">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="" alt="Xbox One S Minecraft Console Bundle 500GB"></a>
            </div><div class="re-compare-title">
            <a href="">Xbox One S Minecraft Console Bundle 500GB</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="re-compare-item compare-item-2439" data-compareid="2439" style="display: block;">
        <i class="fa fa-times-circle re-compare-new-close"></i>
        <div class="re-compare-img">
            <a href="#">Sony PlayStation Move Motion Controller – Twin...</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There is also a jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/HappyiPhone/r3hw5brt/

Hope it helps!

Comment: how does this help?...it alerts undefined also

Comment: I'm using his HTML code not all DIVs have the data attribute in it.

Comment: I realize that (and made same comment above) and that is part of the problem that needs solving

Comment: Sorry, I disagree, the problem that needs solving is HOW TO GET THE data-compareid field from the DIVs he had, and this code shows that. If there are more DIVs that don't have that field he can add them or target the specific DIVs he needs.

Comment: No...they need filtering out. Objective is clearly not to attempt to get attributes from nested elements when the attribute doesn't exist and logic would tell you only get it from the appropriate parent

Comment: OP is not realizing what they are targeting is the main issue. Your answer is not doing anything to improve results they are already getting

Answer (score 0):

@charlietfl thank you for pointing out my mistake I'm taking wrong class name.